# how to prevent TouchEvent from scrolling

Tags: android

I have a custom view, where I have functionality with touch events (swipe etc.). Now it can happen, that this custom view is used within a `ScrollableLayout`. The problem then is, that when the user swipes inside my custom view, the parent (ScrollableLayout) will also handle the swipe gesture and so it scrolls, but it should not.

I need something like `event.preventDefaults()` from JavaScript.

I override `View#onTouchEvent` and return always `true`.
I thought, that when I return true from `onTouchEvent` this means that the event is consumed and no other view will get the onTouchEvent, but that's wrong.

Can anybody help me?

My View is quite easy to test it:

```
public class PreventingTouchEventView extends View {

    public PreventingTouchEventView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.drawColor(Color.RED);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        setMeasuredDimension(200, 200);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

I pushed a example android project to github:
https://github.com/jjoe64/android-preventing-touch-test

If you touch and scroll inside the red canvas, the ScrollableLayout should **not** scroll.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To prevent touches from that layout you have several options:

1) set OnTouchListener, which would always return true.

2) override dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) to always return true

**UPD:** Okey, normally you would have to set OnTouchListener, which would always return true, as I said previously to prevent other views from being called `onTouch`, but with ScrollView it's completely another story.

First of all I will tell how `dispatchTouchEvent` works. It starts dispatching event from the root view to it's child views, so that means that `dispatchTouchEvent` of parent is called *BEFORE* `dispatchTouchEvent` of it's children.

Then in `ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent()` there is a piece of code

```
final boolean disallowIntercept = (mGroupFlags & FLAG_DISALLOW_INTERCEPT) != 0;
if (!disallowIntercept) {
    intercepted = onInterceptTouchEvent(ev);
    ev.setAction(action); // restore action in case it was changed
} else {
    intercepted = false;
}
```

which decides if this touch event should be intercepted, which means if `intercepted` flag is true, then this view would intercept all successive event. And in `ScrollView` `onInterceptTouchEvent` implemented to intercept actions if they are perfroming vertical scrolling.

So my first idea was to set `FLAG_DISALLOW_INTERCEPT` to the parent of your custom view to disallow this opportunity of intercepting events, but this idea fails because of the next lines of code in `ViewGroup`:

```
if (actionMasked == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
     // Throw away all previous state when starting a new touch gesture.
     // The framework may have dropped the up or cancel event for the previous gesture
    // due to an app switch, ANR, or some other state change.
    cancelAndClearTouchTargets(ev);
    resetTouchState();
}
```

So that means that after the `MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN` all states are cleared (and so do `FLAG_DISALLOW_INTERCEPT` is also cleared).

So the final solution is pretty simple

```
public class PreventingTouchEventView extends View {

    public PreventingTouchEventView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.drawColor(Color.RED);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        if (getParent() != null && event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
        }
        return super.dispatchTouchEvent(event);
    }
}
```

this would raise `FLAG_DISALLOW_INTERCEPT` right after first `MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN`, which would dissallow further interception of future actions by parent.

But note, that if your parent view doing some crazy stuff on `MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN` and intercepting this event then you just can't do anything about it, because your parent's `dispatchTouchEvent` are called before your `dispatchTouchEvent`.

Comment: same here. These changes belong to the parent view. I only can change my own custom view...

Comment: Even if I could make changes to the parent, this would completely disable the scrolling. It should only do no scrolling, when I touch inside my custom view.

Comment: Why are you saying that this changes belong to the parent view? You are setting `OnTouchListener` only to your custom view and thus if you touch outside the view - another view should handle this event, in your case it's `ScrollableLayour` (parent of your custom view).

Comment: I tried it. It doesn't matter if I return true. The Scroll layout will also scroll, when I touch my custom view. If you don't believe me, I can publish a demo?

Comment: Wow ! This is solved my problem too .. Thanks a lot Desert :-D

Comment: hmm..I have to add 'return true' after ' getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);' to make it work, why?

Comment: Very well explained! As you explained the key is to ask your parent to not intercept the current touch event with `requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent` in `dispatchTouchEvent`. Thanks! For reference see: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup#requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(boolean)

Answer (score 1):

you have to override parent's onInterceptTouchEvent method

Comment: So it is **not possible** to cancel the whole touch event. I only have the opportunity to do changes on my custom view. The parent view is up to the developers who use my custom view. What a shame