# GridView eats my onTouch events and starts "scrolling"

Tags: android, gridview, touch-event

I am creating an android app in which I need to track the pointer on a couple of elements that are inside a GridView. The problem is that if the pointer moves a little bit up or down, the GridView enters some kind of scrolling mode (even if it fits easily inside the screen), so the events do not reach the child views anymore. Is there anything I can do to prevent this behaviour and keep tracking the pointer inside those children?

So to clarify: the pointer tracking works neatly, until the vertical difference between starting and current position becomes to large. At that moment, no touch event reaches my child elements anymore, and the gridView starts scrolling if it does not fit inside the screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution at [another StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17837881). Simply put, the solution is to create a class that extends the GridView and overrides the onInterceptTouchEvent method, which must return false when scrolling (or any other form of interception) has to be prohibited.